# Nginx URL rewrite /search=string (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to do

> http://domainabc.com/?search=string

Redirect to

> http://domainabc.com/search/string

This is my rule, it's not work. I'm using Laravel 4.

```
location / {
    if ($query_string ~* "\\?search=([^&]+)"){
        rewrite ^/$ /search/%1/? redirect;
    }
}
```

Please help me, Thanks